# Animation follows drag movement

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, windows-phone-7

The purpose of the code below is that a thumb follows a horizontal mouse movement. The code is called upon a mouse event, so the target value of the animation gets updated continuously.

In the code, `offset` is the current mouse horizontal position. The problem is, that the animation of the thumb doesn't fully animate to the specified `offset`, but always seems to be stopping at a value smaller or higher (depending if the mouse is dragged left or right).

The `SeekAlignedToLastTick()` influences the behavior of the animation, although I couldn't figure out what this function does by reading the documentation.

How can I animate the thumb, so that it follows smoothly the drag event?

```
    private Storyboard _thumbStoryboard;
    private DoubleAnimation _thumbAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();;
    private CompositeTransform _thumbTransform = new CompositeTransform();

    private void UpdateUserInterface(double offset)
    {
        var thumbItem = Thumb as FrameworkElement;

        if (_thumbStoryboard == null)
        {
                Storyboard.SetTarget(_thumbAnimation, _thumbTransform);

                _thumbStoryboard = new Storyboard();
                _thumbStoryboard.Children.Add(_thumbAnimation);

                thumbItem.RenderTransform = _thumbTransform;
                _thumbStoryboard.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100));
                _thumbAnimation.EasingFunction = new ExponentialEase();
        }

        double from =  _thumbTransform.TranslateX;

        _thumbStoryboard.Stop();

        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(_thumbAnimation,  new PropertyPath("TranslateX"));

        _thumbAnimation.From = from;
        _thumbAnimation.To = offset;

        _thumbStoryboard.Begin();
        _thumbStoryboard.SeekAlignedToLastTick(TimeSpan.Zero);            
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried to solve your issue, So I've created a Silverlight application and added a Border element for testing.

```
<Border x:Name="Thumb" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="50" height="25" Background="#ff0000" />
```

There was no need to set the "**From**" Property, since the *DoubleAnimation* object could automatically continue from the current Value to the "**To**" Property.

And you were setting the **Duration** to the *Storyboard*, which causes the *DoubleAnimation* to Cutoff its animation without reaching the "**To**" Value, You need to set the **Duration** Property to the **DoubleAnimation** itself instead.

Also there was no need to call _***thumbStoryboard.Stop()***, because it will reset the current animation to the first *TranslateX* Value.

Here is the updated "UpdateUserInterface" function code with comments:

```
        private void UpdateUserInterface(double offset) {
        var thumbItem = Thumb as FrameworkElement;

        if ( _thumbStoryboard == null ) {

            // UpdateLayout Method is update the ActualWidth Properity of the UI Elements
            this.UpdateLayout();

            // Applying the CompositeTransform on "thumbItem" UI Element
            thumbItem.RenderTransform = _thumbTransform;

            // Setting the Render Transform Origin to be the Center of X and Y
            thumbItem.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5d, 0.5d);

            // Setting the target of the DoubleAnimation to be the Thumb CompositeTransform
            Storyboard.SetTarget(_thumbAnimation, _thumbTransform);

            // Setting the Targeted Properity of the DoubleAnimation to be The "TranslateX" Properity
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(_thumbAnimation, new PropertyPath("TranslateX"));

            // Used QuinticEase instead of ExponentialEase
            // and Added EaseOut to make the animation be more smoother.
            _thumbAnimation.EasingFunction = new QuinticEase(){ EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseOut };

            // Initializing the Storyboard
            _thumbStoryboard = new Storyboard();

            // Specifing the Duration of the DoubleAnimation not the StoryBoard
            _thumbAnimation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500));

            // Adding the DoubleAnimation to the Children of the Storyboard
            _thumbStoryboard.Children.Add(_thumbAnimation);

        }

        // Calculate the New Centered Position
        double newPos = offset - (thumbItem.ActualWidth / 2);

        // Set the New DoubleAnimation "To" Value, 
        // There is no need to set the "From" Value since it'll automatically continue from the current TranslateX Value
        _thumbAnimation.To = newPos;

        // Begin the animation.
        _thumbStoryboard.Begin();
    }
```

Hope that helps you :)

Regards,

Monir Abu Hilal